# UITableView variable

Tags: swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am making a video app. Its a UITableView, each row when selected will assign an associated URL to a variable, this variable will be passed through a video extractor and show the user the video. This is how I went about it. 
I have declared my urls:

```
//video links
var calledVideo: String?
let vid1 = "https://youtube.com/1234567"
let vid2 = "https://youtube.com/1234567"
let vid3 = "https://youtube.com/1234567"
```

I am using a variable `var calledVideo: String?` to pass store the video url when a certain row is selected and pass that url into into a video extractor.

My problem is i can't seem to figure out how to change to make my `var calledVideo: String?` equal to `vid1` if row one is selected, `vid2` if row two is selected..etc..
so the magic will be in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but I can't figure out what to set `calledVideo` equal to:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    calledVideo =
    videoExtractor()
}
```

I know it should be super simple, but for some reason my brain cant figure it out today.

Comment: Basically, you should add your video links into an *array* instead of multiple string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your video links into an array, which makes it easy for you to add more videos in the future.

```
let vids = ["https://youtube.com/1234567", "https://youtube.com/1234568", "https://youtube.com/1234569"]
```

And then you can use the `indexPath.row` as the index of the array in `didSelectRow`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    calledVideo = vids[indexPath.row]
    videoExtractor()
}
```